# React native app wont load on android device

Tags: android, react-native, expo

When I try to run my react native app from expo go on my android device it wont load, but works on my Ipad ok.

The screen shows "Downloading Javascript Bundle" then a %. The load freezes on any percentage. It would sometimes load but today wont load at all.

Any ideas what to try?

Thanks
Malcolm

Answer (score 0):

Try running in terminal `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server` and then re run your app

Comment: Im using expo and on a device not emulator. There is no adb??